# How can i access local host running on the same network

Tags: localhost, port

How can i access localhost running on the same network with common router.

Now i have done two thing: Changes the windows host file and added this line

```
192.168.1.5 mysite
```

where 192.168.1.5  is the Ip of the target machine(running Xamp server).

Now if i enter the ip: 192.168.1.5 in my browser i can directly connect to the xamp server Which is great. however i cannot connect to the localhost:81 running on the server.

I tried doing 192.168.1.5:81 to access the service running on port 81 on server but it did not work. The funny thing is I can connect to 192.168.1.5:80 which is the default configuration.

Is there any change i need to make on my machine or the other machine where the Xamp server is running

Comment: What do you mean, you cannot connect to localhost on the remote machine? What doesn't work? Wild guess: you need a hosts entry `127.0.0.1 localhost` on the remote machine.

Comment: i already have that entry

Comment: Trying to restate your problem: you have a XAMP server running at 192.168.1.5:8080 and this server has a php script that you want to access and just browsing to `http://192.168.1.5:8080/myscript.php` does not work? What does your browser say?

Comment: Are you sure XAMP is configured to listen to that address and port? It normally only serves one port and your post indicates it's already at port 80. Am I correct that you can access `http://mysite/myscript.php` when you replace the `myscript.php` with the path to the script that provides the webservice?

Comment: Exactly. I can access it that way

Comment: Why do you expect the service to be available via port 81?

Comment: The service was running on the server on port :81. I solved the issue by disabling the windows firewall which was blocking the port :81. Thanks for helping mabi :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. Turned out that the **Windows Firewall** on the server machine(192.168.1.5) was blocking the **:81 port**. I **disabled** the Windows firewall and Voilà, I could access the web service running on the server.

Now since I cannot leave the firewall disabled, I made an **exception** in the firewall to leave the port :81 open and **enabled** it. Thanks to **Ricky & Mabi** for trying to help me with this issue

Answer (score 1):

If putting in

```
192.168.1.5
```

alone works fine for you, then why are you doing `localhost:8080` ? Try just localhost, and see what your results are. Either way, I'm almost positive that this should be on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) and not here. Hope this helps you still. Or is 8080 a port for something else that isn't XAMPP? I assume it's your Apache port, since you mentioned XAMPP. Please clarify and I'll be happy to edit my answer accordingly. XAMPP should automatically add `127.0.0.1 localhost` in your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts) but you could always check there too, to make sure that it's there. Or, just try `127.0.0.1` in your browser, and see if THAT works. If it does, and `localhost` does not, then your problem may lie in the hosts file.

Comment: 8080 is a port for running a webservice on Apache. How do i get access to this port from a remote machine?

Comment: You may need to forward the port. Is it on a network that consists of a router? If so, you may have to go into the router and try that out. I don't know why it wouldn't work if you're on the same subnet, but... forwarding is definitely worth a try. http://portforward.com/

Comment: Sounds like too much trouble. I figured it might be less complex since i can get direct access to the targets ip and folders. How cant i get access to the service running on that computers localhost

Comment: @AnaMaria Yeah, I'm not really sure, to be honest. If the computer is at 192.168.1.5 and you can access that fine, I'm not sure why localhost wouldn't work on that computer itself. That doesn't really make sense to me either. Have you tried JUST doing localhost though, without the port? That might yield different results. Just a thought! Hope you figure it out.

Comment: Maybe you got me wrong. The localhost runs on that computer. Im trying to access the webservice running on the localhost

Comment: Thanks for you help though. +1 for hearing me out

Comment: @AnaMaria Thanks! I'm sorry I wasn't able to provide more help. Best of luck.